# Delete a file on AppleScript stucks Finder

Tags: applescript

I have written this code to ask for the computer's HDD name and delete a kext on
/System/Library/Extensions but everytime I run it, it stucks the Finder.
Please have a look:

set DiskName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter disk name:" default answer "Macintosh HD")

tell application "Finder"

```
delete (every item of folder "Extensions" of folder "Library" of folder "System" of disk DiskName whose name is "NovatelWireless3G")
```

end tell

Every advice is welcomed.

Thanks in advance,

Spyros

Comment: I'm guessing you are going to need Administrator privileges to delete from a system directory...

Comment: And how do I display a dialog to askd for admin password?

Answer (score 0):

I am no Applescript guru, but I would use this:

```
do shell script "rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/NovatelWireless3G" with administrator privileges
```

but please be VERY CAREFUL testing this. If you want to do something less destructive but which still requires administrator privileges, you could create a file called `junk` in the top-level directory:

```
do shell script "touch /junk" with administrator privileges
```